# How to include session id in APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm running Apex 20.1 and I need to generate some urls that includes the checksum and the session (that's mandatory)

I'm doing :

```
Output := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || ApplicationAlias || ':' || PageAlias || ':' || SessionId ||'::::' || Arguments || ':' || ArgumentsValues, p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');
```

with :

```
-- for example
Arguments := 'param1,param2'; 
ArgumentsValue := 'value1,value2';
```

This command works properly but the URL is missing the session.

The URL Returned is :

```
https://www.example.com/ords/schema/r/myapp/pagealias?
param1=value1&
param2=value2&
cs=3BSsM-dn0SHfT0DBLYTRIHlSC_71paQVC0VQ_Hfa6YuVc-DzsnTzEs6yH
```

Now I need to have the session included in the URL. Means at the end of the URL I should have

```
&session=45654654987
```

I tried adding the session manually like :

```
Output := Output || '&session=' || v('APP_SESSION');
```

This works only for standard pages and not modal pages. So for modal pages I'm doing like :

```
-- Output generated from APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL :
javascript:apex.navigation.dialog(
        '\u002Fords\u002Fschema\u002Fr\u002Fmyapp\u002pagealias?
        param1=value1\u0026
        param2=value2\u0026
        cs=3_XtJdikM6ypsgs1BPNLnh3dKfHI5-gbFl0YMA78wn032WRoN8Z4PoFDOmQJ9RvaMkW1q-Uk-x9BNEaunXyY_hw\u0026
        dialogCs=fC8UqaERKj1k7OONTBxSKhPe4GeVKJ4Mk0nSTNDMRIR0o5hpagnDAKoNiYHzqcWo5Q6FgikwEvkbfQBdNE7MtQ',
        {title:'Page title',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:true,dialog:null},'t-Dialog-page--standard '+'',apex.jQuery('#regionId'));
```

Trick to fix it :

```
Output := replace(Output, ',{title' , '&session=' || v('APP_SESSION') || ',{title');
```

That returns

```
javascript:apex.navigation.dialog(
        '\u002Fords\u002Fschema\u002Fr\u002Fmyapp\u002pagealias?
        param1=value1\u0026
        param2=value2\u0026
        cs=3_XtJdikM6ypsgs1BPNLnh3dKfHI5-gbFl0YMA78wn032WRoN8Z4PoFDOmQJ9RvaMkW1q-Uk-x9BNEaunXyY_hw\u0026
        dialogCs=fC8UqaERKj1k7OONTBxSKhPe4GeVKJ4Mk0nSTNDMRIR0o5hpagnDAKoNiYHzqcWo5Q6FgikwEvkbfQBdNE7MtQ&
        session=98798798797',
        {title:'Page title',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:true,dialog:null},'t-Dialog-page--standard '+'',apex.jQuery('#regionId'));
```

Is there any better way to do this please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: No idea about APEX, but just looking at your code, can't you append ',session' to `Arguments` and its value to `ArgumentValues` as part of the prepare call?

Comment: @AlexPoole That's a good idea. Wich is considering the session as a standard argument and inject it into the function `APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL`. That indeed generates the URL with session in it. However for some reason, Apex doesn't accept this URL. It returns : `Session state protection violation` error. And am unable to explain why the error is raised.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be excluded from the checksum for some reason. Which, if the session is used for the checksum generation, might make some sense I suppose. Sorry, like I said, not my area and I'm out of unhelpful ideas *8-) (Although having said that, I'm looking at the docs and wondering if the `p_plain_url` argument is relevant, since you mentioned modal dialogs; but you might need the JS.)

Comment: @AlexPoole The problem is I don't have any control on what should be taken into account in the Checksum computation. This is done automatically by Oracle/Apex.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `APEX_UTL.PREPARE_URL`, have you tried using [APEX_PAGE.GET_URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/GET_URL-Function.html#GUID-19A879A7-DA63-4519-B50F-DF20F652586E)? In the [APEX 21.2 documentation for APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/PREPARE_URL-Function.html#GUID-A61DFF37-2211-43E4-B7FE-B89C31E151FF), it is recommended to use `APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` instead of `APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL`.

`APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` has a parameter to include the APEX session id so it should properly build the session id into the URL depending the type of page you are navigating to. The checksum will also automatically be generated in the URL as long as you are navigating within the same workspace as your current session.

`APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` will also return the URL in "friendly" syntax if "friendly URLs" are enabled for the application of the page you are navigating to.